# What does the ST prefix stand for, e.g. in ST_Polygonize?

Tags: postgis, terminology

I was just curious, and couldn't find any reference to this anywhere - is it Spatial Types? Spatial Topography? Something else?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I did find it - it stands for **Spatial Type** -

> PostGIS has begun a transition from the existing naming convention to an SQL-MM-centric convention. As a result, most of the functions that you know and love have been renamed using the standard **spatial type (ST)** prefix. Previous functions are still available, though are not listed in this document where updated functions are equivalent. The non ST_ functions not listed in this documentation are deprecated and will be removed in a future release so STOP USING THEM.
>   https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html

---

And **SQL-MM** refers to an ISO standard that defines the spatial types and their associated routines - the MM stands for **MultiMedia** -

> The ISO/IEC 13249-3 SQL/MM Spatial extends the Simple Features data model
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Features
>
> ISO/IEC 13249-3:2016
>   Information technology -- Database languages -- **SQL multimedia** and application packages -- Part 3: Spatial
>   ISO/IEC 13249:2016
>   a) defines concepts specific to this part of ISO/IEC 13249,
>   b) defines spatial user-defined types and their associated routines.
>   Publication date : 2016-01
>   Number of pages : 1328
>   https://www.iso.org/standard/60343.html

Comment: However, it was originally for **spatial and temporal** data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234679/what-is-st-in-postgis